# Why does the stemma appear twice in the footnote?

Tags: footnotes, ledmac

This is annoying, the stemma appears twice when I typeset this. probably something wrong with the `\rhet` command:

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeatletter
% And in the paragraphed footnotes, I'd like no colon too:
\def\parafootfmt#1#2#3{%
  \normal@pars
  \parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  {\bf\printlines#1|}%
  {\select@lemmafont#1|#2}~%
  #3\penalty-10 }
\makeatother
\let\Afootfmt\parafootfmt

%\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Bfootnote{] #2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\raggedbottom


\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \parbox{\LeftWidth}{\raggedleft\textbf{#1}\strut~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%


%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing


\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
 my Lorde \rhet{Robert Dudley}{Around a hundred books were dedicated to Robert Dudley during Elizabeth's reign, see Rosenberg 1958 p. xiii; Adams 2008b}, \rhet{Maister of the Queenes Maiesties horse}{On Elizabeth I's accession in November 1558}, \rhet{one of her highes priuie Counsaile}{appointed in October 1562}, and \rhet{knight of the moste honourable order of the Garter}{elected on 24 April 1559 and installed on 3 June}: Richard Rainolde wisheth longe life, with increase of honour.\\

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tip: By selecting the code parts of your post, and clicking the `{}` button above the text field, the code is properly highlighted (blocks are indented by four spaces, inline code placed between backticks, `\``).

Answer (score 3):

As I said last time, please make your example code *minimal*, you can cut your code down to about a dozen lines.

By 'stemma' I assume you mean the first argument you give `\rhet`, e.g. `Robert Dudley`. In your definition of `\rhet` you have the first argument, i.e. `#1`, two places, so it is printed twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just to place the text on the bottom of the page, for screenshot
\beginnumbering
\pstart
 my Lorde \rhet{Robert Dudley}{Around a hundred books were dedicated to Robert Dudley during Elizabeth's reign, see Rosenberg 1958 p. xiii; Adams 2008b}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GuillaumeCoatalen Glad I could help. Perhaps you might consider going through all your questions, to upvote and accept answers (see the FAQ: http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).